# Best method to allow External Users (CC+ license) to delete records owned by other external users (CC license)?

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, experience-cloud, customer-community-plus, multiple-contacts

Based on [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327316&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1), I know that Salesforce doesn't let you delete any records unless 1 of these 3 criteria are true:

1. The User trying to delete the record is the owner.
2. The User is higher than the owner in the owner's role hierarchy.
3. The User trying to delete the record has the 'Modify All' permission.

**Firstly**, I would like to know: in relation to #2, can I configure External Account Hierarchies in a way that allows some external users to delete records owned by other external users? Do the External Account Hierarchies function in the same way as a role hierarchy for granting this delete permission?

**Secondly**: We have a combination of Customer Community (CC) and Customer Community Plus (CC+) users. CC+ users need to be able to delete records owned by CC users. Is there another mechanism that I am missing to allow this? CC+ Users can have a role in a role hierarchy as far as I understand, but CC users cannot, so they won't actually be "lower" in the role hierarchy will they?

**Thirdly**: How do External Account Hierarchies work when we have Contacts to Multiple Accounts enabled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UPDATE: I think I have ruled out using External Account Hierarchies to do this, because a) they don't seem to work the same as internal Role Hierarchies with regards to granting delete permission, and b) we need the deletion to occur on a Project ro Project basis, not based on Accounts/Organisations. 

Its still unclear how to accomplish deletion in this scenario. I'm finding it hard to believe that there is no solution which would allow us to manage external project teams with cross-user deletion capabilities in Experience Cloud, but its starting to look that way :(